# Brans-Dicke formalism: Validity for curve of scale factor vs cosmic time

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, space-expansion, modified-gravity

Within the framework of the Brans-Dicke formalism, after having run a MCMC sampler and, once the best-fits have been found, I inject them into an ODE system resulting from the modified Friedmann equations, I get the following curve for the factor of scale:

[image: scale factor with Brans-Dicke]

I saw in the literature that there was a lower limit for $\omega_{BD}$ at $40000$ (according to the Cassini-Huygens probe).

Is there an experiment that allowed to have an upper limit?

Indeed, the interval for $\omega_{BD}$ in my MCMCM run is fixed between $40000$ and $50000$. And I find the best-fit, once convergence is reached, equal to $\omega_{BD}=48342$.

I know that when $\omega_{BD}$ tends to infinity, we should find the results of the GR (but from which values we are near to GR, $10^6$, $10^8$ etc... ?)

ps: I have taken $\dfrac{\dot{\phi}}{\phi}\,\simeq\,10^{-4}\,\text{Gyr}^{-1}$ from this paper:

[image: variation of G]